# Spark: is there any method to sort (sort or orderBy ) on column with case insensitive

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i need to sort row in case insensitive way.

i have data like this:

```
+---+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+------+--------------+
| id|      full_name|           job_title|               email|gender|    ip_address|
+---+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+------+--------------+
| 73|     Tina Mccoy|Desktop Support T...|tmccoy20@techcrun...|Female| 23.196.170.54|
| 74|      Lois Hart|        Food Chemist|lhart21@mapquest.com|Female| 145.52.30.236|
| 75|    Thomas Hall|    Senior Developer|   thall22@wired.com|  Male|76.255.197.231|
| 76|  Ernest Romero|             Teacher|eromero23@amazon....|  Male|  99.21.57.239|
| 77|  Irene Bradley| Assistant Professor|ibradley24@squido...|Female| 16.51.179.230|
| 78|Jacqueline Cruz|account Represent...|     jcruz25@cdc.gov|Female| 167.49.98.213|
| 79|    Sara Martin|        Geologist IV|    smartin26@a8.net|Female| 10.145.49.204|
| 80| Johnny Bradley| Executive Secretary|jbradley27@cocolo...|  Male| 138.251.4.102|
| 81|      Fred Dean|Nuclear Power Eng...|fdean28@kickstart...|  Male| 173.10.122.12|
| 82|   Ralph Greene|       Senior Editor|rgreene29@omnitur...|  Male| 57.230.33.105|
+---+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+------+--------------+
```

and when i sort those based `job_title` using `df.orderBy('job_title')` . this is what i get.

```
+---+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+------+--------------+
| id|      full_name|           job_title|               email|gender|    ip_address|
+---+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+------+--------------+
| 77|  Irene Bradley| Assistant Professor|ibradley24@squido...|Female| 16.51.179.230|
| 73|     Tina Mccoy|Desktop Support T...|tmccoy20@techcrun...|Female| 23.196.170.54|
| 80| Johnny Bradley| Executive Secretary|jbradley27@cocolo...|  Male| 138.251.4.102|
| 74|      Lois Hart|        Food Chemist|lhart21@mapquest.com|Female| 145.52.30.236|
| 79|    Sara Martin|        Geologist IV|    smartin26@a8.net|Female| 10.145.49.204|
| 81|      Fred Dean|Nuclear Power Eng...|fdean28@kickstart...|  Male| 173.10.122.12|
| 75|    Thomas Hall|    Senior Developer|   thall22@wired.com|  Male|76.255.197.231|
| 82|   Ralph Greene|       Senior Editor|rgreene29@omnitur...|  Male| 57.230.33.105|
| 76|  Ernest Romero|             Teacher|eromero23@amazon....|  Male|  99.21.57.239|
| 78|Jacqueline Cruz|account Represent...|     jcruz25@cdc.gov|Female| 167.49.98.213|
+---+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+------+--------------+
```

but what i needed is

```
+---+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+------+--------------+
| id|      full_name|           job_title|               email|gender|    ip_address|
+---+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+------+--------------+
| 78|Jacqueline Cruz|account Represent...|     jcruz25@cdc.gov|Female| 167.49.98.213|
| 77|  Irene Bradley| Assistant Professor|ibradley24@squido...|Female| 16.51.179.230|
| 73|     Tina Mccoy|Desktop Support T...|tmccoy20@techcrun...|Female| 23.196.170.54|
| 80| Johnny Bradley| Executive Secretary|jbradley27@cocolo...|  Male| 138.251.4.102|
| 74|      Lois Hart|        Food Chemist|lhart21@mapquest.com|Female| 145.52.30.236|
| 79|    Sara Martin|        Geologist IV|    smartin26@a8.net|Female| 10.145.49.204|
| 81|      Fred Dean|Nuclear Power Eng...|fdean28@kickstart...|  Male| 173.10.122.12|
| 75|    Thomas Hall|    Senior Developer|   thall22@wired.com|  Male|76.255.197.231|
| 82|   Ralph Greene|       Senior Editor|rgreene29@omnitur...|  Male| 57.230.33.105|
| 76|  Ernest Romero|             Teacher|eromero23@amazon....|  Male|  99.21.57.239|
+---+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to pass a computed expression as an argument to `orderBy`. So you can import `lower` function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lower
```

and use it to wrap column name

```
df.orderBy(lower(col("job_title")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution would be to create a `job_title_lower_case` column then sort by that column. In the end result, just drop that new column.